# Solving $3y^2\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}-\left(z-x\right)\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=3y^2$, I keep getting the same wrong answer

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

For the conditions  $x\left(t\right)=t^{\frac{1}{2}},\:y\left(t\right)=t^{\frac{1}{3}},\:z\left(t\right)=0,\:t>0$

I get this:

$$\frac{dx}{3y^2}=\frac{dy}{-z+x}=\frac{dz}{3y^2}$$

$$(I)\:\:\: \frac{dx}{3y^2}=\frac{dz}{3y^2} $$

$$x=z+C_1$$

$$C_1 = x-z$$

$$(II)\:\:\: \frac{dy}{-z+x}=\frac{dz}{3y^2} $$

$$3y^2dy\:=\:\left(-z+x\right)dz$$

$$y^3=-\frac{z^2}{2}+zx+C_2$$

$$C_2=y^3+\frac{z^2}{2}-zx$$

Putting in conditions

$$C_1=t^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

$$C_2=t$$

$$C_2=C_1^2$$

This means that

$$y^3+\frac{z^2}{2}-zx = \left(x-z\right)^2$$

$$2y^3+z^2-2zx = 2 \left(x-z\right)^2$$

$$2y^3+\left(z^2-2zx+x^2-x^2\right)\:=\:2\:\left(x-z\right)^2$$

$$2y^3-x^2+\left(x-z\right)^2\:=\:2\:\left(x-z\right)^2$$

$$2y^3-x^2=\:\left(x-z\right)^2$$

$$\sqrt{2y^3-x^2}=x-z$$

$$x-\sqrt{2y^3-x^2}=z$$

But it's still wrong

So where's the mistake?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $-\dfrac{dy}{z-x}$?

Comment: Yes! Sorry. But I still won't get a solution as I get 2y^3 - x^2 = 0

Comment: Ok. Nevertheless you'll want to update your solution accordingly---no sense making others search for one mistake when another hasn't been resolved.

Comment: Ok i get 2y^3 - x^2 = x - z but still it's wrong

Comment: It's been a while since I've seen the usual terminologies for this sort of problem. Could you remind me what those "conditions" actually mean? They obviously aren't true everywhere.

Comment: The conditions are describing a curve, and we have to calculate the plane which is described by z and goes through that curve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{-z+x}=\frac{dz}{3y^2}$$
You should use the constant $C_1$ instead. Since $C_1=x-z$. Your integration of this differential equation is  not correct.
$$3y^2{dy}=C_1{dz}$$
Integrate.
$$y^3=C_1z+C_2$$
$$y^3=(x-z)z+C_2$$
$$C_2=y^3-xz+z^2$$

---

This line seems not correct to me:
$$y^3=-\frac{z^2}{2}+zx+C_2$$

Comment: But why is my way of integrating it not correct?

Comment: You have both variable x and z but you integrate with dz....This is not correct. @user  I mean  this cant be integrated $\int (-x+z)dz$ you need to have only the z variable.

Comment: You can't consider $x$ as a constant and perform the integration. It  gives you a false answer. @user

Comment: To put a finer point on it, the OPs solution proceeds as though $\int x\,dz=x z+C$. But $x=z+C_1$, so $x$ can't be treated as a constant here.

Comment: But I don't understand why can't I just treat x as a constant? I've done it like that in a previous exercise and got the right solution

Comment: Ok thank you but Op didnt get the right answer. Or maybe I am missing something @Semiclassical

Comment: Of course. I'm just zeroing in on the error you identified.

Comment: But here you dont get the right answer @user

Comment: Ok thank you for your comment @Semiclassical

Comment: Yes but still why can't I just treat x as a constant? What's the mathematical explanation behind that?

Comment: Because $x$ is not a constant here it's a function of $z$ since you have $C=x-z$. You are not taking a partial derivative or something like that. @user

Answer (score 2):

$$3y^2\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}-\left(z-x\right)\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=3y^2$$
You correctly wrote the Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{3y^2}=\frac{dy}{-z+x}=\frac{dz}{3y^2}$$
Don't forget that those ODEs are valid only on the characteristic curves, not elsewhere. Thus solving them leads to chacracteristic curves equations. Other equations of curves are not characteristic curves.

You correctly solved $\frac{dx}{3y^2}=\frac{dz}{3y^2}$  giving the equation of a first characteristic :
$$x-z=C_1$$

In order to find a second characteristic you tried to solve $\frac{dy}{-z+x}=\frac{dz}{3y^2}\quad\implies\quad 3y^2dy=\left(-z+x\right)dz$

If you suppose $z$=constant this ODE is not valid because $z=$constant is outside the characteristic curves. Thus $\int z\,dx\neq zx$ and so :  $\int (-z+x)dx\neq -zx+\frac12 x^2$ as you wrote. That was the mistake.

This would be corrct in integrating on the characteristic $x-z=C_1$ that is $z=x-C_1$ :
$$3y^2dy=\left(-(x-C_1)+x\right)dz$$
$$3y^2dy=C_1dz$$
$$z-\frac{y^3}{C_1}=C_2$$
The general solution of the PDE expressed on the form of implicit equation $C_2=F(C_1)$ is : $z-\frac{y^3}{C_1}=F(C_1)$
$$\boxed{z=\frac{y^3}{x-z}+F(x-z)}$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function.

Condition : $z(t)=0\:;\:x(t)=t^{1:2}\:;\:y(t)=t^{1/3}$
$$0=\frac{t}{t^{1/2}-0}+F(t^{1/2}-0)$$
Let $X=t^{1/2}$
$$F(X)=-X$$
Now the function $F(X)$ is known. We put it into the above general solution where $X=x-z$ :
$$z=\frac{y^3}{x-z}-(x-z)$$
$$\frac{y^3}{x-z}-x=0$$
Solving for $z$ gives the particular solution of the ODE which satisfies the specified condition.
$$z=x-\frac{y^3}{x}$$